# What represents reflection TypeVariable interface

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to read and understand the different interfaces and classes used by java reflection mechanism, but I didn't understand what really represent the instances of classes implementing the `TypeVariable` interface ?

And also the following quotation from [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/TypeVariable.html)  is really ambiguous :

> If a type variable t is referenced by a type (i.e, class, interface or annotation type) T, and T is declared by the nth enclosing class of T (see JLS 8.1.2), then the creation of t requires the resolution (see JVMS 5) of the ith enclosing class of T, for i = 0 to n, inclusive. Creating a type variable must not cause the creation of its bounds.

Can anyone give me a small example explaining clearly what the meaning of the above paragraph?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It represents the type variable for a method, constructor or type declaration, i.e. `T` in the following code snippet

```
public static <T> void f(){}

class A<T> {}

interface I<T> {}

class B {
    <T>B() {
    }
}
```

Note that this is different from a type use, e.g. `Integer` is not a type variable in the following code snippet:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.<Integer>asList(null);
```

Uses of a type variable are not represented by this:

```
public static <T> void h(T t) {}
                         ^
                     Not a TypeVariable
```

Here's the list of uses of the class in the standard API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/class-use/TypeVariable.html

---

Difference to `ParametrizedType`:

A `TypeVariable` refers to the declaration of the type variable, a `ParametrizedType` is a use of such a type.

Example:

```
public class ReflectTest {

    public Collection<String> c;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException {
        System.out.println(Collection.class.getTypeParameters()[0]); // E
        System.out.println(Collection.class.getTypeParameters()[0] instanceof TypeVariable); // true
        System.out.println(Collection.class.getTypeParameters()[0] instanceof ParameterizedType); // false
        Field field = ReflectTest.class.getField("c");
        System.out.println(field.getGenericType()); // java.util.Collection<java.lang.String>
        System.out.println(field.getGenericType() instanceof TypeVariable); // false
        System.out.println(field.getGenericType() instanceof ParameterizedType); // true
    }

}
```

Comment: But doesn't the `T` in your example have another interface that represent it which is `ParameterizedType`?

Comment: So what I understand is that : the `TypeVariable` is representing the abstract definition of type parameter and `ParameterizedType` represents the declaration and use of type parameter?

Comment: @NinjaBoy2014: `TypeVariable` is the declaration of a type parameter, `ParametrizedType` is the use of a type with a `TypeVariable`.

Comment: Thanks really for your great explanation, now the difference between `TypeVariable` and `Parameterized` is clear. One last thing that remains is what is written in my above question about the ambiguous documentation and the resolution from the 0 to n enclosing classes ?

Comment: In Layman's terms: For if you've got nested classes, all classes between the use of the type paremeter and the class where the type variable is declared need to be resolved, i.e. in `class A { class B<T> { class C{ class D { public T t; }}}}` the following classes need to be resolved for using `D.t`: `B`, `C`, `D`

Comment: Thanks really for your great explanations, I wish you really happy life.